# Best environment and Matches, beside Beta, Snail, and small Plecos

Tags: health, fish, aquarium, snails

I own a very small tank, which I'll replace soon, with I think a 40G tank.
I had a betta, and yesterday i bought several fish, of which only the placus, 5 tiny fish, and two snails survived the war, even another kind of aquarium cleaner which I don't know the name of didn't survive...

I own a two outlet air pump, and a very small filter, which takes water from below, and releases it from the top. I'm not sure about these snumber but it says F.Max: 500L/H
And about the air pump: Air Output: 2×4 L/min

Since my fishes' death, I searched several things, and i came across other things too, like snails need pH around 7 I think, or terms like nitrot or something alike, and other things...

Also elsewhere I heard that a woman talked about how a lot of her fish died because of the placus, which I always thought cleaned, but it seem they have more waste that can cause death to others...

So do large fish require water replacement in a short period with a filter attached? what devices do I need to keep them alive? And what's their priority. When should I do a water change? Do I need a live plant environment, and if so, then how should the water get replaced?

I think my snail are of the `Pomacea canaliculata` type. Should I raise the level of stone at some point so they can go outside the water, as I want them to increase? And can it happen in the middle of tank so it will split the tank in two sections, so the snail don't become bait?

I believe I said many things, not to answer them one by one, but to understand my need from this question.

Last shot from my small tank(before fish death): 
Regarding the photo, how fast should I replace my tank, can I wait for next month (20 day in my country)?
[image]
Currently the snails, plocus, beta, and those on the top are alive.

And about the matches, I don't think i can afford more than 40 G, what can match, and how many should be taken so they can co-exist? I know this is a bit general, but I'm not as familiar with fish as you are, so I may learn several names to start with.

Comment: Very confusing story and weird img.
What kind of pleco's you have? Most need a large tank.
Water changes are nessesary but is dependant how "dirty" the water is.. (weekly, every other week etc.) You should always have a filter. Plants are not nessecary, but however some fish like them to have some shelter.

Comment: i already changed the tank :| the store was so noob, i told him a 4 g around 160 littre, and he said that one is around 160~170, and after i took it home, it was only 108 littre :| i put some plant in it... he said they don't need anything, but i can't trust that man, seem to me, he no nothing... not even that much i know as starter person